How to set height of grid cells equal to a sibling's concrete height?
I have a grid & subgrids. The rows contain repeated pairs of [<div> containing [<img>]] followed by [<p>].
I want the heights of every image container (class="frame") to match their sibling <p> heights, i.e.

img container height = sibling p height (line height x1 when p doesn't wrap, x2 or more when p wraps).


I tried div.frame { height=100% }, but it doesn't resize the image within for some reason.
I also tried a trick found in another thread: setting height=0 and min-height=100%, but that seems to cause overflow issues from the column not matching the content width. A couple of other threads have similar suggestions that break the column widths in a similar way. I checked a bunch of other threads but they mostly deal with resizing text / text containers, rather than images / image containers.
So (I think) image sizing somehow behaves differently? I've been having trouble trying to apply those solutions in this case. The images seem to reject it and do their own thing.
I can set a concrete height like 0 or 80px but that won't scale if the text changes. I was hoping some frame height setting would solve it, but idk.
Here's what I have so far:
HTML


* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: tan;
  color: black;
}

div.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(2, auto auto) / repeat(4, max-content);
}

.grid > div.row {
  grid-column: span 4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.row > div.cell {
  grid-column: span 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
}

.cell > div.frame {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.frame > img.icon {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.cell > p.note {
  width: min-content;
}
<div class=grid>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="frame">
        <img class="icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Emoji_u1f0cf.svg">
      </div>
      <p class="note">Matthew Patel</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="frame">
        <img class="icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Emoji_u1f0cf.svg">
      </div>
      <p class="note">Lucas Lee</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="frame">
        <img class="icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Emoji_u1f0cf.svg">
      </div>
      <p class="note">Todd Ingram</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="frame">
        <img class="icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Emoji_u1f0cf.svg">
      </div>
      <p class="note">Roxie Richter</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I went with this layout because grid seemed useful for keeping things aligned even with various image sizes.
Anyway, that's how I got to this point. Maybe I don't understand "100%"? Help and feedback appreciated.

I would first simplify your HTML structure then update the CSS like below.


body {
  background-color: tan;
  color: black;
  margin 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  justify-content: start;
  gap: 20px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  width: fit-content;
}

.cell {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

img.icon {
  height: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.cell > p.note {
  width: min-content;
}
<div class=grid>
  <div class="cell">
    <img class="icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Emoji_u1f0cf.svg">
    <p class="note">Matthew Patel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <img class="icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Emoji_u1f0cf.svg">
    <p class="note">Lucas Lee</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <img class="icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Emoji_u1f0cf.svg">
    <p class="note">Todd Ingram</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <img class="icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Emoji_u1f0cf.svg">
    <p class="note">Roxie Richter</p>
  </div>
</div>



